# Updating DATE datatype based on id#

Tags: sql-server

I have a date of birth field that was imported with a few errors and I'm trying to correct them.  I'm using the query

```
UPDATE myTable
SET DOB=2012-04-10
WHERE id=123456
```

And I am getting the error

```
Msg 206, Level 16, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

This seems logical enough to me, but not to SQL Server, any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put an apostrophe around the date:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET DOB='2012-04-10'
WHERE id=123456
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  DOB is most definitely of the 'date' datatype, however.

Comment: I have the date and the month backwards.  Luckily enough the actual value that I used was a date over 12 so the action failed.  That's why I was getting the conversion error.

Comment: it's often best to take a step back and return in a couple minutes when you have a seemingly intractable problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET DOB='2012-04-10'
WHERE id=123456
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a syntax error. Try this

```
UPDATE myTable
SET DOB='2012-04-10'
WHERE id=123456
```

Comment: i tried that, but it gives me the error conversion failed when converting data and/or time from character string.  Opening the table in design view and checking shows that DOB IS of the date datatype, however.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your date in single quotes. SQL needs the quotes to delineate where the value begins and ends

```
UPDATE myTable
SET DOB='2012-04-10'
WHERE id=123456
```

Answer (score 1):

What datatype is the DOB column?

Try

```
SET DOB = '2012/04/10'
```

Also best to stick it in a transaction when your updating just incase.  Rollback has saved my ass so many times.